# MapCoder issue after updating Beam to 2.35

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

After updating Beam from 2.33 to 2.35, started getting this error:

```
def estimate_size(self, unused_value, nested=False):

estimate = 4 # 4 bytes for int32 size prefix

> for key, value in unused_value.items():

E AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' [while running 'MyGeneric ParDo Job']

../../../python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py:677: AttributeError
```

This is a method of MapCoderImpl. I don't know Beam enough to know when it's called.

Any thoughts on what might be causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Beam uses [`Coder`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#specifying-coders) to encode and decode a `PCollection`. From the error message you got, Beam tried to use `MapCoder` to decode your input data. It expected a `dict` but received a `list` instead, hence the error.

Additionally, Beam uses the transform functions' type hints to infer the `Coder` for output `PCollection`'s elements. My guess is that you might use a wrong return type for your function. Assuming you are implementing a `DoFn`'s `process`, you `yield` a list in the function body, then you 'd see the error above if you define the function like this:

```
def process(self, element, **kwargs) -> List[Dict[A, B]]:
```

Beam sees the output element's type hint, `Dict[A, B]`, and decides to use `MapCoder`. You might want to change the type hint to the one below, so that Beam could actually use `ListCoder`:

```
def process(self, element, **kwargs) -> List[List[Dict[A, B]]]:
```

More about benefits of using type hint is describe [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-type-safety/#benefits-of-type-hints).